# How do I protect quotes in a batch file?

Tags: perl, batch-file, quotes

I want to wrap a [Perl one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program#Perl) in a batch file. For a (trivial) example, in a Unix shell, I could quote up a command like this:

```
perl -e 'print localtime() . "\n"'
```

But DOS chokes on that with this helpful error message:

> Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

What's the best way to do this within a [.bat file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Perl stuff on Windows, I try to use the generalized quoting as much as possible so I don't get leaning toothpick syndrome. I save the quotes for the stuff that DOS needs:

```
perl -e "print scalar localtime() . qq(\n)"
```

If you just need a newline at the end of the print, you can let the `-l` switch do that for you:

```
perl -le "print scalar localtime()"
```

For other cool things you can do with switches, see the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) documentation.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows' "DOS prompt" (cmd.exe) you need to use double quotes not single quotes.  For inside the quoted Perl code, Perl gives you a lot of options.  Three are:

```
perl -e "print localtime() . qq(\n)"
perl -e "print localtime() . $/"
perl -le "print ''.localtime()"
```

If you have Perl 5.10 or newer:

```
perl -E "say scalar localtime()"
```

Thanks to [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/jf-sebastian)'s comment.

Comment: good answer, just marginally less good than the one I accepted. Thanks!

Comment: perl -le "print localtime()" -- prints '2625625810842681' instead of 'Thu Sep 25 06:25:26 2008', perl -E"say scalar localtime

Comment: This also works [may print "Tue Aug  4 02:54:07 2009"]: perl -le "print scalar localtime()"

Answer (score 2):

For general batch files under Windows NT+, the ^ character escapes lots of things (<>|&), but for quotes, doubling them works wonders:

```
C:\>perl -e "print localtime() . ""\n"""
Thu Oct  2 09:17:32 2008
```

Answer (score 1):

In DOS, you use the "" around your Perl command. The DOS shell doesn't do single quotes like the normal Unix shell:

```
perl -e "print localtime();"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, any answer you get to this is command-specific, because the DOS shell doesn't parse the command-line like a uniq one does; it passes the entire unparsed string to the command, which does any splitting. That said, if using /subsystem:console the C runtime provides splitting before calling main(), and most commands use this.

If an application is using this splitting, the way you type a literal double-quote is by doubling it. So you'd do

```
perl -e "print localtime() . ""\n"""
```